# Python3 - retrieving Facebook html

Tags: python, html, facebook

```
<a class="_2wma" href="https://www.facebook.com/SMRTCorpSG/?ref=page_internal">SMRT</a>
```

I am trying to retrieve the text in the `<a></a>` however when i tired using the method below, the outcome is an empty list `[]` . Did i make a mistake here?

```
r = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
name = soup.find_all("a",{"class": "_2wma"})
print(name)
name2 = soup.find_all("a", {"href": "https://www.facebook.com/SMRTCorpSG/?ref=page_internal"})
print(name2)
```

Comment: You have two prints. Which one causes the wrong output? What do you want to find with the second query?

Comment: Both output is the same. Both will result in an empty list.

Comment: How did you assign a value to `soup`?

Comment: You second query searches for all `<div>` tags that belong to class `"https://www.facebook.com/SMRTCorpSG/?ref=page_internal"`. Are you sure you have any of them?

Comment: Hi @DYZ i realised there is a typo. But even when i changed the `<div`> to `<a>` it still return an empty list.

Comment: Your first query is correct (`name = soup.find_all("a",{"class": "_2wma"})`). It works for me and returns `[<a class="_2wma" href="https://www.facebook.com/SMRTCorpSG/?ref=page_internal">SMRT</a>]`.

Comment: @ScottHunter i have updated the code.

Comment: @DYZ It doesn't work for me though. It is weird that it keep returning `[]` .

Comment: Are you sure your `r.content` has the data?

Comment: Check if you can find any links at all with `soup.find_all("a")`. If not, @BishwasMishra is probably right and you have no content.

Comment: Hi @DYZ and @ Bishwas Mishra . Thanks for all the help. There are contents in soup, in fact all the `<a>` tag, however it does not contain the one i want. It seems fishy as the `<a>` tag below it can be found.

Answer (score 1):

the attribute should be href and not class for the second one

```
name2 = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "https://www.facebook.com/SMRTCorpSG/?ref=page_internal"})
```

should be

```
name2 = soup.find_all("a", {"href": "https://www.facebook.com/SMRTCorpSG/?ref=page_internal"})
```

also make sure you put the correct value when instantiating BeautifulSoup. Try to print r.content to check it.

```
print(r.content)
BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
soup.find("a", attrs={"class": "_2wma"}).text
```

Comment: Hi fam. Thanks for helping. The outcome is still an empty list `[]`.

Comment: That means your soup doesn't have the a tag. Cross check the content of `soup`.

Comment: Hi. I have check the content of the soup. There are only contents below the one i wanted. It is weird to me as they are suppose to be from the same `<div>` above.

Comment: There are too many contents in `soup` my console got over flooded and maybe that is why i cannot find the specific tag?

Comment: Print `soup.findAll(a)` to debug.

Comment: Hi. My friend tried my code on his pc and it is working. Somehow it doesn't work on mine. so i will be moving on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.